# ASP.NET Core 6 app fails to start up on IIS in Windows 11 ARM OS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, arm64, .net-6.0, windows-11

Just today, Microsoft released a new Windows 11 ARM update that finally supports IIS. This in theory opens up .NET developers for being able to fully develop .NET apps on the newer Macbook Pros with M1 chips.

However, I'm running into trouble getting my ASP.NET Core 6 app to run in IIS on Windows 11 ARM.

In the advanced settings for the app pool in IIS, there is a new option "Enable emulation on ARM64". If I have this turned off (the default), then when I try to launch my app it stops the app pool and logs this error in the event log:

> The Module DLL 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Asp.Net Core Module\V2\aspnetcorev2.dll' could not be loaded due to a configuration problem. The current configuration only supports loading images built for a ARM64 processor architecture. The data field contains the error number. To learn more about this issue, including how to troubleshooting this kind of processor architecture mismatch error, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=29349.

If I enable the ARM64 emulation setting for the app pool, then I get this error on app startup: HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start. The event log shows this error:

> Activation context generation failed for "C:\WINDOWS\system32\conhost.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\WINDOWS\system32\conhost.exe" on line 0. Invalid Xml syntax.

Has anyone else gotten their ASP.NET Core 6 apps to run successfully on IIS within a Windows ARM environment?

Comment: "This in theory opens up .NET developers for being able to fully develop .NET apps on the newer Macbook Pros with M1 chips" is rather interesting a statement, when .NET 6 itself is native on Mac M1 models. Why do you think IIS is a mandatory part of the story when actually it can be completely excluded? (No doubt someone else downvoted.)

Comment: @LexLi IIS is a huge part of the story for our development team, we have multiple ASP.NET 6, ASP.NET Core 3.1, and Angular apps that run through IIS. IIS allows for what we need: impersonation of Windows users, https SSL support, and subdomain support. I'd love to see you achieve all of that directly in macOS.

Comment: HTTPS/subdomain support can be easily achieved on Mac with other web servers/reverse proxy products, or even ASP.NET Core itself with YARP https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy The only thing missing on Mac is the impersonation of Windows users. If your projects rely on that then of course Windows is your only option, but many have migrated to OAuth and claims based solutions which work across all main stream OS.

Comment: @LexLi I didn't want to over complicate my question by providing details on our entire ecosystem, but we even have applications still on .NET Framework, which doesn't run on Mac. Beyond that, I tried for our .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 6 apps using reverse proxy as well as another product and, like you said, ran into the windows impersonation issue (which we have to use because SQL Server authenticates through the app pool user.) And your assumption that we're not using OAuth or claims is incorrect, we use Identity Server with OIDC. Can we stick to my actual question now?

Comment: FWIW I'm having the same error running a legacy ASP.NET 4.8 WebForms application, on Windows 11 Preview with Visual Studio 2022 17.3 Preview (both ARM). However, despite the same error in the Event Viewer, for me it seems related to **IISExpress** which just crashes upon F5'ing to start up and debug the project. No resolution yet.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get my ASP.NET apps to run under IIS within Windows 11 Preview for ARM, on my new Macbook Pro with an M1 chip; not just with .NET 6 ASP.NET apps but also with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and ASP.NET Framework apps (the new IIS app pool "Enable emulation on ARM64" setting works great!) To get past the errors in my original post, I had to:

1. Repair my ASP.NET Core Runtime install.
2. Repair my Windows Hosting Bundle install.
3. Change my web.config to launch the dotnet app in a different way:

   < aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments="exec "bin\Web.dll"" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess" >

...had to be changed to:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="bin\Web.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
```

I believe the repairs were required because I had originally installed ASP.NET Core and the Hosting Bundle before installing IIS (since IIS didn't exist yet for this OS!)

## 2023 Update:

If you upgrade to .NET 7 or .NET 8 and are getting the dreaded "The current configuration only supports loading images built for a AMD64 processor architecture" error, then what you'll want to do is follow the instructions in the [ancm-arm64 github repo](https://github.com/lextm/ancm-arm64), which will replace some of your ASP.NET Core dll's with patched ones that work on ARM chips. If any Microsoft devs come across this post, you really should apply this patch in the ASP.NET Core installer.

Comment: Hi Justin, I am using the m1 as well trying to run .net 4.8 application. (Works in iis express but not via IIS). What do you mean by repair the runtime? Which runtimes/sdks did you install to get .net 4.8 running on IIS? I get an error on iis that aspnetcorev2.dll count not be loaded despite that the website is .net 4.8

Comment: @Bodokh Since you're not using .NET Core or .NET 5+ then the .NET Framework 4.8 SDK for x64 should be all you need, in conjunction with the app pool setting mentioned for enabling emulation on ARM64.

Comment: @Bodokh You also posted to Microsoft forum https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1183655/unable-to-run-net-4-8-apps-on-iis-using-arm-proces so please check my updated answer there with more details.

Comment: In short, this answer focused on x64 (or x86) application pools (ARM64 can emulate that and the new IIS application pool setting `enableEmulationOnWinArm64` was set to `true` by default to enable this). That's why by installing the .NET 6 ASP.NET Core bits (runtime and hosting bundle) things magically worked for you (even with IIS OOB like URL Rewrite module). **Note that .NET 7/8 is a different story, but that requires a new question.**

Comment: If you are using .NET 7 or 8 instead of 6, you might want to patch your installation on Windows with my patch to get ARM64/x64/x86 running side by side on IIS, https://github.com/lextm/ancm-arm64

Comment: For running .net 4.8 applications on iis on ARM - what worked for me is uninstalling the "URL Rewrite" module and also the "web platform installer" - either this or uninstalling the dotnet-hosting which removes the aspnetcorev2.dll but then you cannot run an app that was built for .net 7 from iis